# Android, Generics and inhertitance

Tags: java, android, generics

The title may be bit confusing but here is what I am facing

I have a class:

```
    public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity<T> extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
    Dialog progessDialog;

    public abstract void displayData(T output);

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == PROGRESS_DIALOG) {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            progessDialog = progressDialog;
        }

        return progessDialog;
    }

    class PerformOPTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, T> {
        // connector=new JSONConnector();
        Connector connector;
        String curUrl;
        Class<T> clazz;

        PerformOPTask(String url, Class<T> curClazz) {
            //connector = new UnitTestConnector();
            connector = new JSONConnector();
            curUrl = url;
            clazz = curClazz;
        }

        @Override
        protected T doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return connector.getData(URLUtils.getFormattedUrl(curUrl),clazz);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(T output) {
            displayData(output);

        }
    }




}
```

Then I have a subclass as :

```
public abstract class BaseListFragmentActivity<T> extends BaseFragmentActivity<T> implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

    protected ListView mList;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.table_list);
        CommonUtil.getActionBarWithBackButton(this,getLayoutInflater());
        mList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.table_list_listView);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onBackABButtonPressed(View view) {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public abstract void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3);


}
```

Now I am extending this class as below:

```
public class ListAccountsActivity<T> extends BaseListFragmentActivity<AccountData> {

    protected Acct[] mItems;
    private String[] mIcons;
    protected boolean displayHandledBySubClass=false;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);


        new PerformOPTask(getString(R.string.get_account),AccountData.class).execute();
        showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        //.getData(URLUtils.getFormattedUrl(getString(R.string.get_account)),actData);




    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View view, int position, long id) {
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Acct account = (Acct) mList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AccountDetailViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedAccount",account);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayData(AccountData output){


        if(displayHandledBySubClass){
            //handle display in subclass
            handleDisplayData(output);
        }
        else {
            Acct[] accountArray = new Acct[output.getAccount().size()];
            mItems = output.getAccount().toArray(accountArray);
            IWMArrayAdapter<Acct> adapter = new IWMArrayAdapter<Acct>(this, mItems);
            adapter.setIcons(mIcons);
            adapter.setArrowNeeded();
            //mList is superClassVariable
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);
            dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void handleDisplayData(T output){

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tapped search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_servers_menu, menu);

        // Calling super after populating the menu is necessary here to ensure
        // that the
        // action bar helpers have a chance to handle this event.
        return true;
    }


}
```

My Question is can I make **handleDisplayData** generic in some way so that I can pass any type to it. What I am trying to do is to reuse logic in **BaseListFragmentActivity** as much as possible and handle the only task specific to **ListAccountsActivity** or its subclass in that class/subclass.

I hope my question is clear, Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to use type-specific methods from the base in the subclass, and for that you need to make everything generic:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T> { ... }
public abstract class ExtendedGeneric<T> extends GenericBase<T> { ... }
public class ExtendedGenericSub<T> extends ExtendedGeneric<T> { ... }
```

Point being that if `ExtendedGeneric` extends `GenericBase<DataOutput>`, only methods of `GenericBase<DataOutput>` are accessible from `ExtendedGeneric`.

Comment: What I want to be able to do is to implement displayData in ExtendedGeneric except for the case where I want  ExtendedGenericSub to handle dislay in which case I will use handleInSubClass method. THe challenge I am facing is I can get either a DataOutput or some other type say ServerOutput which are unrelated but if DataOutput is the type I want to handle in ExtendedGeneric but if type is ServerOutput I want o handle in ExtendedGenericSub, handleInSubClass method

Comment: A usage example is worth a thousand words. Right now I'm not sure what you mean by "getting another type" -- is `handleInSubClass` getting called from some other method? Or is it getting called on some other object in `displayData( DataOutput )`?

Comment: I am sorry, here is how it will be invoked: displayData( dataOutput ), in which case I dont want to call handleInSubClass but displayData( serverOutput ), should invoke handleInSubClass(serverOutput).

Comment: Then if `handleInSubClass(T)` needs to use anything in `GenericBase<T>`, PaulMurrayCbr's answer is the thing to do, if it doesn't you can also follow Edwin Bautista's answer.

Comment: I have added the actual class I am using. This is for use in an android project using asynctask if that helps. Thank you again for your and all others time.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
public abstract class ExtendedGeneric<C> extends GenericBase<DataOutput> {

boolean handleInSub;

@Override
public void displayData(DataOutput t) {
    if(handleInSub){
        handleInSubClass(getValue(t));
    }

    //handle here
    System.out.println(t);

}

protected abstract void handleInSubClass(C c);
protected abstract C getValue(DataOutput t);
```

}

This is of course only assumes that the data type C will come from DataOutput t. The idea is you can also make the ExtendenGeneric parameterized so you can make the classes extending it controls the datatype supplied to handleInSubClass.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

**GenericParent**

```
public abstract class GenericParent<T> {

    public abstract void displayData(T t);

}
```

**GenericChild**

```
public class GenericChild<T> extends GenericParent<GenericChild> {

    @Override
    public void displayData(GenericChild t) {
        // Do Something Here...
    }

    /**
     * Using protected better than public,
     * to prevent other class access directly to this method.
     * But make sure this the other class is not same package with this GenericChild,
     * because if it same package than the other class can access directly this method.
    **/
    protected void handleSubClass(T t){}
}
```

**SubClass**

```
public class SubClass extends GenericChild<SubClass> {

    @Override
    public void handleSubClass(SubClass t){
        // Do Something Here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about this kind of thing?

```
class Vehicle {};

abstract class RoadVehicle extends Vehicle {
  abstract int getNumberOfWheels();
}

class Truck extends RoadVehicle {
  int getNumberOfWheels() {
    return 8;
  }
}

class Car extends RoadVehicle {
  int getNumberOfWheels() {
    return 4;
  }
}

abstract class GenericHandler<T extends Vehicle> {
  public abstract void displayData(T t);
}

abstract class RoadVehicleHandler<T extends RoadVehicle> 
    extends GenericHandler<T> {
  public void displayData(T t) {
    System.out.println(t.getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels");
    specialStuff();
  }

  abstract void specialStuff();
}

class CarHandler extends RoadVehicleHandler<Car> {
  void specialStuff() { /* honk horn */ }
}

class TruckHandler extends RoadVehicleHandler<Truck> {
  void specialStuff() { /* flash lights */ }
}
```

Comment: It's ok using `default` modifier if your all class in same `package`, but if you want access from the other `package` make sure to make it `public`.